# How to buy the plane?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I've been buying iron mining machines for 3 days. I get 400 iron bars per minute right now, and the costs for the minimng machines is higher everytime.

This is going to last weeks until I can amass 9.000.000 iron bars, necessary to buy the plane.

Maybe I missed something. It is strange to me that the game turn so difficult to continue. There is anything I can do to improve my iron bars obtention rate?

Comment: The iron production rate changed in 0.9.4 beta update

Comment: So, "weeks" have passed, did you manage to buy the plane?

Comment: @Zommuter I can't remember how I did it, but I beated the game long ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The honest answer would be waiting just as long as it takes for you to be able to afford 100 new mining machines, buy them, wait again etc. until the time required to obtain the (now) 5e6 ironbars for the plane.

The cheating answer is, open a JavaScript console and enter `ironbars = 5e6`

Comment: The more important thing I wanted to know at that moment is if there were something to do different than just "waiting as long as it takes" that I maybe missed. So this answer means no (apart from cheating). Thanks

Comment: I found no other at least. Of course one could also fork the [source](https://github.com/gamehelp16/thegoldfactory) and introduce some additional mechanic...

Comment: I think they fixed the difficulty to get the plane on later releases

Answer (score 2):

(I literally wrote this answer like 50 min ago on a different post)
To get extra iron bars (or anything) in The Gold Factory, you would need to edit the save game code. Do this by changing the decoding the base 64 save game code. You can use this website. https://www.base64encode.org/ The second number after the decryption should be the number of iron bars you have, while the first number is the amount of gold bars you have. Change that, then encrypt the code again. Add "encrypted" to the end of the code, and there you go! Here's my code:

MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDB8MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDB8MTZ8MTYwfDMzfDYwfDEzNHwwfDJ8MXw1OTB8MXwxfDF8Mjd8MXwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDN8MHwxfDN8NHw0fDF8MnxZb3V8VGhpcyBpcyB5b3UufDB8MHwwfDB8ZmFsc2V8ZmFsc2V8ZmFsc2V8MHxmYWxzZXx0cnVlfHRodW5kZXJ8NXwzfDF8MTd8ZmFsc2V8MHw5OTk5OTk5OTl8OTk5OTk5OTk5fDB8RGlhbW9uZCBTd29yZHx0cnVlfHRydWV8dHJ1ZXx0cnVlfHRydWV8dHJ1ZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXx0cnVlfDV8ZmFsc2V8dHJ1ZQencrypted